# Laravel $request->input() is getting url path together with the query param name

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, path, request

I am having a route which gets multiple records from a database. There are possible filters to be applied to it as query parameters. For example cid.
In my controller I am doing a `$chosen_category = $request->input('cid', 0);` and it gets it just right when working on localhost.
However when testing on a real domain, the first request param is broken, because it gets the whole path together with the name. So my variable always equals to the default (0).

This is the output of print_r($request->all()):

On localhost:

> Array
> (
> [cid] => 33
> )

On site domain:

> Array
> (
> [//items/getAll?cid] => 33
> )

My route is defined as

> Route::prefix('items')->group(function () {
> Route::get('/getAll', [App\Http\Controllers\ItemsController::class, 'getItems']);
> });

And I am making a request from the frontend to `"items/getAll?cid=33"`. It executes the right function with everything else correct, just this first param is with wrong name. The domain is of type subdomain.domain.com if it matters.

Why is it acting different from localhost? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading about issues with query params, I checked the output of the `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` variable and found out it is the same (`//items/getAll?cid=33` instead of just `cid=33`) so the problem was with the web server, not with my code.

After finding this I searched for the issue and started looking through the config files of the web server (it's Nginx).
Turned out changing one line in the nginx conf for this domain solved the issue:

Before: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?/$request_uri;`

After: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;`

(I'm not the one who sets the servers so I didn't know what this is doing.)